# ¿Dónde implementar mi primer sitio web para compartirlo y probarlo?

Tags: python, hosting

Terminé mi primer sitio web de python, que pueden clonar [desde GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/myflaskapp), y me gustaría implementarlo en un servidor de prueba gratuito. ¿Tienes ideas?

Probé pythonanywhere.com, pero por el momento no puedo cambiar el punto de origen del código donde se lanza el sitio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En efecto prefiero que comience desde `/home/MikeP/mysite/myflaskapp` porque es ahí es donde hay todo lo que desarollo o incluso desde [este depósito GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/myflaskapp) si es posible.

Intento hacerlo sobre [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/moodbotbot/activity/builds/0970b2c2-9aba-49d8-b3e0-a96c4eb71db9) pero tambien pero me decia:

```
-----> Compressing...

 !     Compiled slug size: 529.6M is too large (max is 500M).

 !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: podrias revisar esta opcion: https://www.openshift.com/trial/

Comment: Hola, te recomendaría [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com), es el mas accesible, gratuito y sencillo de utilizar que he visto hasta el momento. He probado otros como GoDaddy y Heroku y luego no quise trabajar nunca mas con estos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaría probar con AWS (Amazon Web Services). Puedes probar  sus muchos servicios durante un  año gratis (si no excede sus muy generosas concesiones).
Tienen muchas opciones para el deployment, incluyendo docker y lambda.
También es bueno de saber si vas a buscar trabajo programando, ya que en el entorno empresarial está muy de moda (por buenas razones ).
Suerte.